# Are there any penalties for swapping out heroes?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do equipment buffs work on towers when switching characters?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45950/how-do-equipment-buffs-work-on-towers-when-switching-characters)

In Dungeon Defenders you can swap out a hero during the build phase to create a variety of defenses. Is there a penalty to the defenses that are built in this way? Or are they just as strong as the ones that are built by the active hero?

Comment: [This](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45950/how-do-equipment-buffs-work-on-towers-when-switching-characters) is related, and the answer there probably answers your question.  It's a bit close to call if it's a dupe or not though.

Comment: @agent86 It does cover the question, I guess my google-fu failed earlier. It almost seems like that one covers this one by happenstance though. I'd vote we leave this one in case people search for hero swapping like I did earlier.

Comment: @Rapida Shouldn't we still close as a dupe though then? AFAIK, that's what the dupe function is for, to direct people to a single right answer that's been asked in different ways.

Comment: @FAE That works, as long as it stays around to point them towards the other question. If something is closed as a dupe does it hang around?

Comment: @Rapida Yep, there will be a link in this question to another if it's closed as a dupe. This isn't the kind of dupe that warrants deletion, so it'll stick around to direct people to the other one.